# sheet with function and button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new with swift and SwiftUI

Why .sheet not working with function ? When I try the below code, I get this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)'

Here is my code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var search = ""
    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField("search", text: $search)
            Button("search") {
                self.show.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
                self.googlecom(D: self.search)
            }
        }
    }

    func googlecom(D: String) -> some View {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/\(D)") else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        return Text("")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SwiftUI` almost everything requires or returns a `View`, so look carefully into interface declarations. Here is about `sheet`

```
/// Presents a sheet.
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - isPresented: A `Binding` to whether the sheet is presented.
///     - onDismiss: A closure executed when the sheet dismisses.
///     - content: A closure returning the content of the sheet.
public func sheet<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, 
              @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View
```

As it is seen content is `ViewBuilder` that should provide a `View`, so your function (if you want use function) code should look like

```
func openall() -> some View {
    print("Hello")
    return Text("Sheet content view is here")
}
```

Comment: Non-void function should return a value

Comment: sure, you don't return anything here `guard let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/\(D)") else { return }`

Comment: but why is sheet here? what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: its ok now i cancel sheet and work with button thank you asperi

Answer (score 0):

**You need to return a view**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var show = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button("GO") {
                self.show.toggle()
            }

            .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
                DetailView()
            }
        }
    }


}
```